# Loading script before all images have been preloaded

Tags: image, preloading

I'm creating a gallery of images with a thumbnail strip below. I would like to preload these images so that when the user clicks a thumbnail, the image immediately appears. There are quite a few photos though, so I don't want to wait until all images are preloaded until the user is able to click on a thumbnail. How do I allow for the images to load in the background, while allowing the user to click on a thumbnail and that photo appearing?

Here is the page for reference: http://tinyurl.com/lk6e2yx

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery for example you can do something like

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "IMG.thumbnail", function(event){ ... });
```

That would enable the handler for any element matching now or future with the selector.